# How do I handle blank strings and invalid Uri's in a text box bound to a uri property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uri

In my WPF application, I have a text box that is bound to a property that is a Uri.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Margin="0,0,4,4" x:Name="txtExportURL" Text="{Binding Path=ProjectExportURL, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Visibility="{Binding Permissions.CanExportJson, Source={x:Static services:ApplicationUserInfo.Instance}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

I'm trying to do validation on the string coming from the text box as follows

```
private Uri _projectExportURL;
 public Uri ProjectExportURL
 {
   get { return _projectExportURL; }
   set
   {
      if(Uri.TryCreate(value, value.AbsoluteUri, out _projectExportURL))
         _projectExportURL = value;
      else
         _projectExportURL = null;
      this.OnPropertyChanged("ProjectExportURL");
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the string is blank or an invalid Uri and it does `TryCreate` it doesn't fail and go to the else statement. It just fails and does nothing.

How can I make sure blank strings and invalid Uri's get set to null?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that?

```
if(value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) || !Uri.TryCreate(value, value.AbsoluteUri, out _projectExportURL))
    _projectExportURL = null;
OnPropertyChanged("ProjectExportURL");
```

Not sure what is *blank* Uri.

Comment: @Sintar not blank Uri's, blank strings. If a user does not enter a value into the textbox the string is empty and that will get passed to the property which is invalid. I will try this though.